# Log shipping a large database

Tags: sql-server, cross-domain, log-shipping, vldb

I have Question on log shipping: 
I am migrating a VLDB (12TB) SQL database from a physical environment (server A) to virtual environment (server B), and from version SQL 2008 R2 to SQL 2014. The high-level plan for migration is to log ship from server A to server B during a transition\test period. Once we’re happy with testing we simply make server B the new production environment. During this period server B needs to receive periodic log restores (once or twice per day) and be in read-only\standby mode for testing. 
I have the added complexity of A and B existing in related but different domains, and I also want to use the existing .trn files that are currently being created via the existing Ola Hallengren regime. So basically, I just want to utilize the COPY & RESTORE aspects of log shipping on server B by picking up trn’s from a network share.
Before I attempt this with the VLDB I am testing the concept on a much smaller DB. The issues I’m getting are :-
When I try to get server B into standby mode I get this error:-

"This backup cannot be restored using WITH STANDBY because a database upgrade is needed. Reissue the RESTORE without WITH STANDBY"

stack overflow Questions 3010115 and 40760521 are similar but unfortunately provide no solution. I've tried a couple of workarounds but no luck yet.
Any help or other suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

*** I would guess. Talk to Steve G! I'm glad I didnt have to do this!

This sounds like it doesn't like the fact they are running on different versions. The trans file requires having an upgrade process on it first before you do the restore. You are out of luck. Try going from 2008 > 2008 then upgrading the server after.

Comment: ha haaa :-) love it :-)

Comment: its actually a nice job, now that we have some storage capacity in place the fun can really start :-)

Comment: the version upgrdade shouldn't be too much of an issue, at least we're forwards and not backwards!